# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of null

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of null`  randomly when dragging a polygon inside a google map. I mean, most of the times when I drag the polygon works as expected, but rarely a few times fails.

In the Google Chrome console, the error shown is:

1) Error header:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of null js?libraries=drawing,geometry:87
```

2) Error body:

```
_.I.hasListeners    @   js?libraries=drawing,geometry:87
_.I.trigger @   js?libraries=drawing,geometry:88
W1  @   poly.js:20
_.t.mm  @   poly.js:82
_.I.trigger @   js?libraries=drawing,geometry:88
(anonymous function)    @   js?libraries=drawing,geometry:34
_.I.trigger @   js?libraries=drawing,geometry:88
(anonymous function)    @   common.js:79
_.I.trigger @   js?libraries=drawing,geometry:88
Mm  @   common.js:69
(anonymous function)    @   common.js:225
(anonymous function)    @   common.js:225
```

Edited: 
Instead of pasting the chunks of code, I provide a fiddle as an example with the code working:
https://jsfiddle.net/w6Lnk47u/16/

The error seems to be in this line:

```
var isMarkerContained = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(CREAR_CAMP.markerWithLabelCasaClub.getPosition(), CREAR_CAMP.polygonArea);
```

To reproduce the error, someone has to:

1) Click on the left-enabled one first and draw a polygon on the map.

2) Click to the right now enabled button (when the draw of the polygon finishes it enables) and it will appear a marker inside the polygon. Now is when the error could come. Someone just have to try moving and resizing the polygon (trying to leave the marker out of the polygon area) and it will appear the error in the Google Chrome console. As I said, it happens randomly and few times.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: What's at `common.js:225` and `:79` and where do you call it?

Comment: @Kenney, in my JavaScript at least that I know I do not call explicitly any anonymous function in an external common.js file.

Comment: @geocodezip I've provided the whole JavaScript code of the page.

Comment: How is that "minimal"? You should also provide any required HTML/CSS.

Comment: @geocodezip I hope it's going to be enough: 
https://jsfiddle.net/w6Lnk47u/7/
Let me explain a little bit how it works: you have two buttons. Click on the enabled one first, then draw a polygon on the map. Then click to the other button and it will appear a marker inside the polygon. Now is when the error could come. You just have to try moving and resizing the polygon (trying to leave the marker out of the polygon area) and it will appear the error in the Google Chrome console.

Comment: @Kenney I've found that the anonymous function calls to common.js are linked to this file https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/23/6/intl/es_ALL/common.js.

Might the error be related to loading more than libraries at once? I wonder this because I've just tried to add the places library and I got a similar error.

Comment: It could be. You'd have to debug. Find what source code goes with each line of the stack trace, and start with the one that's in your own code. You can set breakpoints in the JS console. You'll want to use the original source code of the JS, not the minified/uglified versions for this. Often times such an error comes from some DOM query returning null instead of an expected element.

Comment: It wasn't related to adding more than one library at once, the error I was having with places library was another issue.

Comment: I've been debugging for a while before posting the question. I should have said it before, but the line where it breaks was in this line:

var isMarkerContained = oogle.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(CREAR_CAMP.markerWithLabelCasaClub.getPosition(), CREAR_CAMP.polygonArea);
or the following if check.

Comment: Have you checked out this [issue posted back in '11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058094/google-maps-api-cannot-read-property-e3-of-undefined)? It may be a bit helpful. If not, there's a same [issue submitted](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-map/issues/121) on the GoogleWebComponents repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2019**: I was unable to reproduce the problem again, the error must had been fixed from Google.

---

It's seem to be a bug with Google.

Here is a fiddle with the minimum code that [Google suggests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools) for drawing: https://jsfiddle.net/TomKarachristos/hc7nwwdx/. I only change the options.

if you play enough you will see that the same error is triggered, so is not a problem in your code.

if you want not appear this error you must use the window.onerror:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
  #maybe some condition code
  return true; //suppress error
}
```

but I don't  recommend it.

Comment: Just trying, the beach flag icon in your fiddle is not well-linked, you could change it to https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png.

I'm still not able to reproduce the error. Do you have a use case in which it appears? I tried to draw lots of shapes and also change its draggable vertexs.

In my fiddle, one thing I was wondering, was if the fact of using within a loop the `google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(randomLatLng, CREAR_CAMP.polygonArea);` could provoke not to have access to the geometry library momentary.

Comment: Go make some polygon, and play with the vertexes, try to make some strange shapes. I have see the error with only one polygon.

Comment: Error caught, I just haven't tried enough with the polygon resize and adding or removing vertexs. Thanks, I though my code has the error and I couldn't find out how to solve it. As you provide, I'll make use of the `window.error` to prevent it.