# Getting Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined google maps

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I get an error on my javascript. It is a script that get my coordinates from a tr table. I think it is something with my listener, but i'm not sure. Nothing works..

somebody know the reasen of the error?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var markers = [];

    function init_map() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 7
            , center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.452928, 4.789983)
            , mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);

        $('table tr').each(function (idx, item) {
            var coordsStr = $(this).find(".coords").html();
            if (!coordsStr) return;
            createMarker($(this));
        });
        $('a').click(function (evt) {
            var coordsStr = $(this).parents().find(".coords").html();
            var coords = coordsStr.split(",");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
            map.setCenter(point);
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[coordsStr], 'click');
        });
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers["52.939347, 4.754741"], 'click');
    }

    function createMarker(jqe) {
        var coordsStr = $(jqe).find(".coords").html();
        console.log(coordsStr);
        coords = coordsStr.split(",");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map
            , position: point
        });
        var content =  jqe.find("td").eq(0).html(); + '<br>'
        var content1 =  '<strong></strong><br>'+jqe.find("td").eq(2).html(); + '<br>'
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(content+content1);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        markers[coordsStr] = marker;
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
```

Comment: Does this question not help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058094/